# Inheritance in SQL Server with parent object id

Tags: sql, sql-server

While seeing the details of tables created in `sys.tables`, I saw two columns, one is `object_id` and the other is `parent_object_id`.

`Object_id` represents the `id` of the object. Does `parent_object_id` refer to a parent table/object? Is there some implicit way of implementing inheritance? Or is this `parent_object_id` used for some other functionality?

Comment: More than likely the parent object id is a foreign key value to the parent table. This is part of relational database design. This is how to associate a child item with it's parent.

Comment: If you look at the documentation you will realize that sys.tables is a view which is looking at sys.objects. Then look at the documentation for sys.objects and it explains it quite clearly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

The `parent_object_id` is defined as:

```
parent_object_id    int     ID of the object to which this object belongs.
                            0 = Not a child object.
```

in the [relevant MS Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql) - it's an inherited columns from the base `sys.objects` catalog view.

Things like columns have `parent_object_id` set to denote which "parent" object (here: which table) they belong to. But tables themselves aren't "child" objects - they don't "belong" to anything else, so their `parent_object_id` will always be 0.

SQL Server tables don't know any concept of inheritance per se. Sure - you can map your objects to various tables and somehow get the "illusion" of inheritance - but that's still handled by a number of stand-alone tables, which are linked together via common columns etc. - but you cannot *really* inherit tables in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

All the tables should have `0` in that field, which means that is not a child object.